# R Shiny - Passing data into drop-down input selector

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a drop-down selector in Shiny. The Shiny tutorial has this code in ui.r:

```
selectInput("var", 
    label = "Choose a variable to display",
    choices = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
      "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian"),
    selected = "Percent White"),
```

If I go into RStudio and write:

```
myVar = c("Percent White", "Percent Black",
          "Percent Hispanic", "Percent Asian")
```

myVar is of type chr.

In my project, I want to load an .RData object in server.r. When I run:

```
mydata = load("myDataFile.RData")
```

mydata is then of type chr and contains the name of all the objects within the .RData file.

I want to have a drop-down select from everything in mydata (the names of the objects in my .RData file). I'm having trouble passing this mydata list from server.r to ui.r.

If I do anything in server.r like

```
output$myChoices = c(mydata)
output$mydat = mydata
```

and in ui.r like

```
choices = mydata,
choices = output$mydata,
or choices = "mydata",
```

I either get that it doesn't recognize mydata or the only choice available in the dropdown is literally "mydata."

Also, the following successfully prints out all the objects within mydata:

```
#server.r:
output$text4 <- renderText({ 
      paste(mydata)
    })

#ui.r:
textOutput("text4"),
```

It makes sense how "mydata" would literally print "mydata," but that's the syntax to print the text.

Again, I want a drop down to choose from everything within mydata.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Can you share what `mydata` looks like? `head` or `names` or some output?

Answer (score 2):

All the info you need to create the `selectInput` is in the `server.R` part so you could use `uiOutput`/`renderUi` to create it there.

You could for example add `uiOutput("select_data")` in your `ui.R` and in `server.R`:

```
output$select_data <- renderUi({
selectInput("choose_data", 
    label = "Choose data",
    choices = mydata
    ) 
})
```

You can then access what the user has chose in `server.R` using `input$select_data`